# Is a Kalman Filter applicable for irregular, infrequent measurement?

Tags: kalman-filter

I have taken on a project previously approached by someone else, looking at sensor data. Each sensor produces about three days of data (sampling about once a second), and each day a calibration is carried out, producing some calibration parameters about the behaviour of the sensor.

To tackle the problem of measurement uncertainty in the calibrations they have applied a Kalman Filter, where the state vector is given by the calibration parameters, and the observation vector is the actual voltage values output by the sensor at calibration.

Ignoring the quality of their model for a moment (it seems as though it could use work), I feel that using a Kalman filter to combine ~3 measurements over a 72 hour period is at least overkill, if not actually unsuitable. Is this feeling right, or misguided (or does it depend on specifics)?

Comment: If the model is correct then the Kalman filter computes the sequence of filtering distributions exactly, no matter how many observations are missing. However, doing so when the data is sampled very sparsely over time may not be the fastest way to compute them. You may be able to modify your model to have observations at every "time" but with time-varying dynamics, and still use the Kalman filter but with one update per actual observation, not per second. What is it that you are worried about exactly when you say "unsuitable"?

Comment: To clarify, the Kalman filter is only applied to 3 measurements, spaced at about 24 hours - there's no "missing" data according to the model. I can see the benefit of the filter when there are many measurements and the truth gets "zeroed in on", as in most of the examples that I've seen, but I guess that my worry is with so few measurements a Kalman filter does not add enough to warrant the increase in complexity.

Comment: I missed the part about 3 observations total. In that case you probably can't reliably identify the state dynamics anyway (except from out-of-data knowledge) so I'm not sure how helpful that would be here. We're not in a position to evaluate whether the "increase in complexity" is worth it for you or not (especially since the algorithm is widely available in software and would run in a tiny fraction of the sampling interval, so does not seem particularly complex to me).